# How to create Notification.contentView in android Nougat and above?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat

I use `Notification.contentView` to replicate notification views:

```
View notificationView = notification.contentView.apply(context, parent);
```

Unfortunately as of version N, `Notification.contentView` may be null and deprecated, so how can I create `Notification.contentView` manually?

Generally I create notification this way:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
builder.setAutoCancel(true)
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setWhen(when)
        .setSmallIcon(smallIcon);
```

Then if I create the contentView manually, what can I do to map all the above settings?
Important note: I don't call setCustomContentView, I want to reproduce a contentView for the standard notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer my own question:
Create `contentView` by `Notification.Builder`:

```
builder.createContentView();
```

Create `contentView` by `Notification`:

```
Notification.Builder.recoverBuilder(context, notification).createContentView();
```

Since `Notification.Builder.createContentView()` was introduced in api level 24, so the above code can only be called from Nougat 7.0 or newer devices; For a lower version phones, it's always safe to reference non-null Notification.contentView directly, it's created automatically by the android system after builder.build() was called.

Answer (score 3):

> [**`Notification.contentView()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#contentView)

- **`YES`** From android **N**, this field may be `null`
- The notification view is determined by the inputs to [**`Notification.Builder;`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder) a custom `RemoteViews` can optionally be supplied with [**`Notification.Builder.setCustomContentView(RemoteViews)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setCustomContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews))

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Nilesh_channel";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Your Notifications",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationChannel.setDescription("");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_layout);

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setCustomContentView(notificationView) // set here your RemoteViews
            .setAutoCancel(true);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: If you don't add a custom contentView, how do NotificationCompat.Builder.set* methods affect the resulting contentView?

Comment: @QLocker didn't get you

Comment: @QLocker if you use `custom contentView`  than all `NotificationCompat.Builder.setting` will not work you have to manage with your custom view

Comment: I don't use custom contentView, I just want to know how android creates the contentView for a standard notification before android Nougat, then I will use the same method when contentView is null when android Nougat+.